# DotNet.Highcharts 4.0: chart download not working

Tags: c#, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

We are using the nuget package DotNet.Highcharts 4.0 in an (quite old) project. The chart is generating correctly, but when trying to download it as a pdf, the pdf is empty.

When clicking the download as pdf link, a http (not https) post request is made to 'export.highcharts.com' and the svg it sends in the form-data is a valid svg. Or at least it is valid when I save it to a svg-file and open it in Edge.

I can't find any information support has endend.

Comment: Hi, DotNet.Highcharts is one of the community wrappers and is not officially supported. I recommend using the Official Highcharts .NET wrapper https://dotnet.highcharts.com/

Comment: I changed it to use the Official Highcharts .NET wrapper, but with no effect. The generated pdf is still empty.

Comment: What version of Highcharts .NET wrapper do you use now?

Comment: I'm now using the nuget package Highsoft.Highcharts Version 11.0.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I discovered it has something to do with the http request made and a security feature from Firefox. It works fine in Edge (after ignoring a warningmessage about information being send over http). I can get it to work in Firefox also, but you need to set an advanced configuration property in `about:config -> dom.block_download_insecure = false`. This is not something a regular user would know/can change.

Comment: You're right, it shouldn't be the default behavior. In my case everything works correctly; perhaps your project includes some deprecated configuration. Could you please check if you run the following script? `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>`

Comment: I downloaded the newer javascirpt files from highcharts.com and it is now working correctly (and i also changed it to offline exporting)